# Using Node.js as an environment variable in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, selenium, jenkins, node-webkit, npm-install

I am attempting to run Protractor End-To-End tests in `Jenkins`.
The tests are being run on a windows slave that has `Node.js` installed on it. For reasons that are unknown to me I cannot get the Node.js plugin on Jenkins so I have been trying to find another way around it.

Thats where "Prepare an environment to run" from EnvInject comes in. EnvInject is already added to our Jenkins.

I am unsure on how to use it however currently I have the following

`Path = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe;C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm`

In the properties content section.
If this is correct how do I use this to then do `npm install` so that I can get files that I need for setting up the selenium server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your path to contain the directories containing the nodes and npm executables, not the executables themselves.  Also, it's been a long time since I used Windows, but I think PATH should be upper case.  So you need:

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

Then if you run "npm install" for example, Windows will search the PATH for directories containing npm.exe.